# CasperJs and Jquery with chained Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select, casperjs

I'm trying to create a testing case for a web site which includes a form with 3 chained selects.
The first select is populated by default when the web page is loaded. If any option from the first select is selected, then 
the second select is populated via an ajax call. In the same way, when an option is selected on the second selected, so the 
third select is populated via an ajax call. Finally, when an option is selected on the third select, a html table is populated
with the information than I need to validate.

The three interconnected selects have this struct

```html
<select id="s1" name="s1"> 
 <option value="1">Option1</option>
 <option value="2">Option2</option>
 <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>

 <select id="s2" name="s2"></select>

 <select id="s3" name="s3"></select>
```

I know for sure that the web site use Jquery for to do the ajax call.
Somebody has or know a clean way for create this case with casperJs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I did it. Because the web context includes jQuery, we can use it to trigger events, and an important step is that we have to wait and validate after each ajax call  before to process any next step.

```
//set select values
var optionFirstSelect  = 125;
var optionSecondSelect = 6;    
var optionThirdSelect  = 47; 

//create casper object
var casper = require('casper').create({
    loadImages:false,
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

//open url
casper.start('http://thewebsite.com');

casper.then(function(){

    //select option on first select
    this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
        $('select#s1').val(valueOptionSelect);
        $('select#s1').trigger('change');
    },optionFirstSelect);

    //wait until the second select is populated
    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.evaluate(function() {
            return document.querySelectorAll('select#s2 option').length > 1;
        });
    }, function then() {

            //select option on second select
            this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
                $('select#s2').val(valueOptionSelect);
                $('select#s2').trigger('change');
            },optionSecondSelect);

            //wait until the third select is populated        
            this.waitFor(function check() {
                return this.evaluate(function() {
                    return document.querySelectorAll('select#s3 option').length > 1;
                });
            }, function then() {

                    //select option on third select
                    this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
                        $('select#s3').val(valueOptionSelect);
                        $('select#s3').trigger('change');
                    },optionThirdSelect);

                    //wait until table with info is populated after an option is seleted on third select. 
                    this.waitFor(function check() {
                                return this.evaluate(function() {
                                    return  document.querySelectorAll('table#info tbody tr').length > 1;
                                });
                            }, function then() { 

                            //Do verifications here ...
                    });               
            });         
    }); 
});

casper.run(function() {
    //finish execution script 
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Great example for "Cascaded select options". Just want to mention that to prevent spagetty like code , it 's recommended to use casper.then() and casper.thenEvaluate() functions instead of casper.evaluate() .

Answer (score 3):

The right and easiest way to do this is to fire 'onchange' event on the first select after you changed value to need option, then the same on the second one:

```
//...
// the first select
casperjs.thenEvaluate(function() {
    var sel1 = document.getElementById('s1');
    sel1.value = 3;
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent('change', true, false);
    sel1.dispatchEvent(evt);
});

// the second select
casperjs.thenEvaluate(function() {
    var sel2 = document.getElementById('s2');
    sel2.value = 'someVal2'; // guess, you know needed value
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent('change', true, false);
    sel2.dispatchEvent(evt);
});

// the third select
casperjs.thenEvaluate(function() {
    var sel3 = document.getElementById('s3');
    sel3.value = 'someVal3'; // guess, you know needed value
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent('change', true, false);
    sel3.dispatchEvent(evt);
});

casperjs.then(function() {
    // your verifications here
});
```

Comment: Several years have passed, but I want to thank and confirm that Serge S. solution works. Nice job Serge!  In my case, I'm using AngularJS in the <select> element with ng-change="myChange()".  What was happening is the Angular "change" was not called.  Most of the other solutions around the internet used a variant of: $('#select_element_selector').val('value').change(); but this won't work. The trick (as stated by Serge) is to dispatch the event.