# How to scrape ajax loaded content with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, scrape

I have used JSOUP for scraping and its works perfectly till the ajax and javascript not playing their roles to display webpage content .

Now guys any clue  , how  to scrape those content which get displayed with ajax or by JavaScript after page get loads completely .

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a headless browser as [PhatomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

In order to ease your work, You could use  [CapserJS](http://casperjs.org/)

> CasperJS is a companion for PhatomJS which brings a greatly improved API to ease the creation of scraping and automation workflows.

These tools are very useful when you have to scrape a websites with dynamic content, for instance, websites where the content is displayed after it ran process in Javascript (sometimes including ajax calls).

You can see a example about how casper works here:
[CasperJs and Jquery with chained Selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283908/casperjs-and-jquery-with-chained-selects/16300933#16300933)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly with JSoup. You'll need a *headless browser*, which is a much more complex thing. There are headless versions of Firefox, Safari, and others. Searches for "headless X" (where X is the browser engine you want to use) should turn up some useful projects.