# Easiest way to create a spider from manual jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, web-crawler, mechanize, casperjs

I have what would best be described as a jQuery "script":

```
//  Get the Textbooks URL
window.location = $($("li.dropDown").find("a")[0]).attr('href');

//  Fill in Department Data
var depts = $($(".deptSelectInput")[0]).next().children();
$($(".deptSelectInput")[0]).val($($(".deptSelectInput")[0]).next().children().text());
$($(".deptSelectInput")[0]).blur();

//  Fill in Course Data
var courses = $($(".courseSelectInput")[0]).next().children();
$($(".courseSelectInput")[0]).val($($(".courseSelectInput")[0]).next().children().text());
$($(".courseSelectInput")[0]).blur();

//  Fill in Section Data
var sections = $($(".sectionSelectInput")[0]).next().children();
$($(".sectionSelectInput")[0]).val($($(".sectionSelectInput")[0]).next().children().text())
$($(".sectionSelectInput")[0]).blur();


//  Submit the form, only if it's valid
if (($(".noTextBookCourseErrorMessage")[0].style.display) == "none") {
    formSubmission();
}


//  Extract all the ISBNs from the page
var regex = /\d+/g;
var isbn = $('li:contains("ISBN")').text().trim();
var isbns = [];

var tempIsbn = regex.exec(isbn);
while (tempIsbn) {
    isbns.push(parseInt(tempIsbn[0], 10));
    tempIsbn = regex.exec(isbn);
}

console.log(isbns);
```

It does exactly what I need to do.

When I open up dev tools in Chrome and post this script three separate times (once to load a new URL, once to get the data and submit the form, once to read from new page), it returns to me exactly the data I want.

I'm very new to spiders and was wondering what the best way would be to automate that process. Basically, I need a script I can run that will do what I just did (break-down of three jQuery posts).

I've looked into CasperJS and mechanize, but never used either.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, where the web context that you are trying to crawl includes dynamic content through JQuery, CasperJS is an excellent option if you want to use Javascript in order to achieve that. You can use it to trigger events, add process steps, include functions to wait and validate after each ajax call before to process any next step.

Here an example how crawl a website with CasperJS and JQuery 
[CasperJs and Jquery with chained Selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283908/casperjs-and-jquery-with-chained-selects/16300933#16300933)

For execute javascript code from CasperJS, You have to use [evaluate()](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.evaluate) method

> The evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you're entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console.