# How to run my js function after clicked a button add the dom has reloaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler

I want to use js to crawl a website, But the website use the ajax to paging the contents. At first, you can only  crawl the first page content. the you must click a button(next page), the  website use the ajax to update content of the webpage.

Qustion: I can use js to find the button, and click it. but how I know when the page has reloaded.and I can to get updated contents.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can directly send request to the next page's ajax target and interact with the response. There must be a pattern for "next page" request url.

Comment: Good Idea.But the click event do much complex thing, so I wish I can simulate the click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, where the web context that you are trying to crawl includes dynamic content through AJAX, CasperJS is an excellent option if you want to use Javascript in order to achieve that. You can use it to trigger events, add process steps, include functions to wait and validate after each ajax call before to process any next step.

Here an example how crawl a website with CasperJS and JQuery 
[CasperJs and Jquery with chained Selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283908/casperjs-and-jquery-with-chained-selects/16300933#16300933)

Here an example how crawl a website with CasperJS and just Javascript 
[CasperJS dynamic selectlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780014/casperjs-dynamic-selectlists/16244031#16244031)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "headless" browser for such a task:

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

[Casper](http://casperjs.org/)

Especially the [click](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.click) function of casperJS could be used to what you intended.

Or the given exmple to fill out forms is dead simple:

```
casper.start('http://google.fr/', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
});
```

From [Quickstart](http://casperjs.org/quickstart.html) of casperJs.